# How to create dynamic slave in jenkins

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins

I have requirement to create dynamic slave in jenkins ,the backgroud is i would be creating dynamic cloud instances on run time in linux.So I wont be knowing the fixed  IP address   for slave configuration.So please help to explain to create slave dynamically .Is there any already existing plugin available or need to write groovy script.

How i could use [RemoteLauncher](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sshslaves/RemoteLauncher.java) .I am new to grrovy script.Are there any simple steps to achieve..

Thanks

Comment: What type of cloud service are you using? Are you considering using docker for running instances?

Comment: I am using Eucalyptus cloud services provided internally in our company.How to use docker services,i am not aware.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to Docker, as you can configure a docker image with your environment and you can configure jenkins to launch dinamically any docker container instances you need.

I recommend you to check the Docker documentation and these plugins:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin